# source code for monodroid map tutorial

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android

i'm trying to follow this tutorial here

```
http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Maps_and_Location/Part_2_-_Maps_API
```

but am stuck at the overlay part.. some part of the article mentioned that there's supposed to be a source code that came with the tutorial but I can't find it anywhere... anyone here knows where to get the supposed source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code is linked to from the [first page](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Maps_and_Location) of the tutorial: [MapsAndLocationDemo.zip](http://docs.xamarin.com/@api/deki/files/529/=MapsAndLocationDemo.zip)